# How do I get a latitude,longitude,state,and country using a zip code against the apache module maxmind mod geo ip

Tags: php, apache, api, maxmind

I'm able to get the following from the current client using the `mod geoip`:

```
$slat=apache_note("GEOIP_LATITUDE");$slon=apache_note("GEOIP_LONGITUDE");$scntry=apache_note("GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE");
```

However if I have a standalone zip code (possibly international) that I need to get the latitude and longitude and state and country for from this module how do I do that?

Comment: When you're running in a webserver, that code gives you the data for the current connection. How would a "standalone zip code" relate to any connection being processed by the webserver?

Comment: @covener so there is no way to obtain information from passing a zipcode somehow into the module?

Comment: That doesn't appear to be the purpose of the Apache module, API, or database provided by maxmind.

Answer (score 0):

This is a geolocation module that translates IP address to other information. You cannot find information using ZIP code or postal codes.